# Change background of react app according to Chakra UI color mode

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, chakra-ui

I am new to Chakra UI and React, and would like to to implement a background changing according to the color mode of Chakra(dark/light).

I have tried several versions, I could use any of them(there are no limitations), but none of them worked:

- Dynamic SVG component as background - had positioning issues.
- Trying    to change SCSS variables with react on color mode change
- Trying to read color    mode from the cookies in SCSS as the chakra
  ui color mode is stored    in the cookies
- have an inline styled component with `useColorMode()` hook - this is partially working, but only if I refresh the page(tried `useEffect()` and `useMemo()` as well but did not help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically fixed it with turning the background opacity of the SVG to 0, this way, the color mode of the page is visible.